# Keycloak Rest API 404 not found

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to get the groups using the endpoint from here:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/#_groups_resource

```
GET /{realm}/groups
```

When I do a GET request on

```
http://localhost:8080/supercatalog/groups
```

I get

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>404 - Not Found</body>

</html>
```

Why is this happening? Is the endpoint that I'm using not the right one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this happening? Is the endpoint that I'm using not the right
> one?

The endpoint is incorrect the correct form is:

```
http://<KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME>
```

So in your case:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/supercatalog/groups
```